# Update chart inside Cardview in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, bluetooth

I'm writing an IOS app to control some bluetooth device.
I used the library given for the device which is written in **Objective-C**, and I'm coding in **Swift**.

I need to implement the following method of the protocol written in **Objective-C**:

`-(void)didReceiveData:(NSData*)data Device:(DFBlunoDevice*)dev;`

Xcode automatically propose the following function in **Swift**:

```
func didReceiveData(data: NSData!, device dev: DFBlunoDevice!) {

}
```

However I get the following error:

> Protocol requires function 'didReceiveData(_:device:)' with type '(NSData!, device: DFBlunoDevice!) -> Void' (__ObjC.DFBlunoDelegate)

Any help would be welcomed :).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works. :)
I have the feeling that swift doesn't like parameter that start with an upper case character.
So here is what I did:

**In Objective-C Protocol**
 I changed the method
`-(void)didReceiveData:(NSData*)data Device:(DFBlunoDevice*)dev;`
to
`-(void)didReceiveData:(NSData*)data mDevice:(DFBlunoDevice*)dev;`

**In Swift class**
I changed the name of the parameter from:

```
func didReceiveData(data: NSData!, device dev: DFBlunoDevice!) {

}
```

To:

```
func didReceiveData(data: NSData!, mDevice: DFBlunoDevice!) {

}
```

And for people who might be using the same library as I am (**DFBlunoNano**), doing this should highlight 2 other uses of this method in the library, just change `Device` to `mDevice`. ;)